# how to find the timestamp that an interface flapped

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, interface

could you please advise on how I could see
when was the last time that an interface has flapped on a linux host ?
(centos, if it makes a difference)

i have tried the following:

```
ethtool -S eth0
ip -s link
cat /proc/net/dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see when an interface changed status to up and down, you can look at the system log file like `/var/log/syslog`, or `dmesg` output.

You will a line that is similar to the following:

```
r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link down
r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link up
```

You may get a different interface name `eth0` and/or different driver name `r8169`. Clearly, the first line shows when an interface goes down and other when it becomes up.